# Import accounts of Ropsten node in localhost to metamask

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, metamask, ropsten

I have ropsten node in localhost:8545 with 2 accounts. Inorder to connect ropsten and metamask I need wallet seed... From where I could get wallet seed for accounts in localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your local Ropsten node, you can find the JSON account files in `<DATADIR>/keystore`. [[more info](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts)]

Once you are logged in to MetaMask (new wallet or existing wallet), you can import a JSON account file (encrypted private key) or a private key.

**i. Select "Import account"**

[image]

**ii. Select "JSON File", type the password and click on "Import"**
[image]